# sbcl,slime上でlispbuilder-examplesのタイトルバーが正しく表示されない

Tags: macos, common-lisp, lisp

OSX10.10です。
 SBCL1.2.10
 lispbuilder-sdl

quicklispでlispbuilder導入後、sbcl、slime上で

```
(sb-int:with-float-traps-masked
(:invalid) (sdl-examples:particles))
```

を実行するとタイトルバーが真っ白で正しく表示されません。
画面描画は正しくされているのですがマウスやキーボードでの操作は受け付けませんでした。

ターミナル上でサンプルを実行すると問題なく動作します。

しかしターミナルでも似た動作を発生する時があり

```
(sb-int:with-float-traps-masked
(:invalid) (sdl-examples:particles))
```

では正しく動くのですが

```
(sdl-examples:particles)
```

と実行するとFLOATING-POINT-INEXACTが発生、ABORTして
そのまま

```
(sb-int:with-float-traps-masked
(:invalid) (sdl-examples:particles))
```

を実行するとタイトルバーは銀色なのですがボタンとタイトルが表示されません。
 何か解決方法があればご教授頂ければとお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://code.google.com/p/lispbuilder/wiki/DownloadInstallation の下の方にコメントがあり、どうも `~/.swank.lisp` に

```
(setf swank:*communication-style* :fd-handler)
```

と書いておくとよいようです。

こちらの環境は以下の通りです:

- SBCL: sbcl @1.2.10_0+fancy (macportsでインストール)
- Emacs: emacs-mac-app @5.4_0 (macportsでインストール)
- SLIME: 2.13 (quicklispでインストール)
- OS: MacOS X 10.9.5

;; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18345464/cl-opengl-under-slime-on-macos-crashing-sbcl-bug が関連しそうな気がします(私はあまり追っていませんが)。

Answer (score 1):

まず、`FLOATING-POINT-INEXACT`が発生した場合ですが、一度発生してしまうと画面描画に影響を与えてしまうのかもしれません。  
ですので、続けて他の物を実行しても似た症状が出る可能性があります。原因が特定できるまでは、一度エラーになったら、処理系を落す方が問題を追い掛けやすいかなと思います。

また、`SB-INT:WITH-FLOAT-TRAPS-MASKED`で囲うのは、`FLOATING-POINT-INEXACT` を処理する為ですので、`SB-INT:WITH-FLOAT-TRAPS-MASKED`で囲むのが無難だと思います。

次にターミナルで実行はできてもSLIMEでの実行が上手く行かない件ですが、何らかの原因で評価が上手く行かないのかもしれません。

```
(defun p ()
  (sb-int:with-float-traps-masked (:invalid)
    (sdl-examples:particles)))
```

という関数SLIME上で定義して、

```
(p)
```

を実行してみた場合は、改善するでしょうか。

## ※追記

```
(defun foo ()
  (let ((width 500) (height 500))
    (sdl:with-init ()
      (sdl:window width height :position nil :title-caption "test")
      (sdl:with-events ()
    (:quit-event () t)
        (:key-down-event ()
             (when (sdl:key-down-p :sdl-key-escape)
               (sdl:push-quit-event)))))))

(foo)
```

とするのがウィンドウを出す最小限のコードみたいです。  
これを実行すると500x500のウィンドウが表示される筈ですが(escで終了)、これもSLIMEではどうでしょうか。

## 追記 SLIME環境依存問題の切り分け

sbclを起動します

```
(ql:quickload :lispbuilder-sdl)
(ql:quickload :lispbuilder-sdl-examples)

(sb-int:with-float-traps-masked (:invalid)
  (sdl-examples:particles))
```

を入力して起動することを確認します。
escで終了します。

次に

```
(ql:quickload :swank)

(swank:create-server :port 7777 :dont-close t)
```

と入力しswankを起動します。

次に、Emacsを起動し
`M-x slime-connect`を実行し Host:`127.0.0.1`、Port:`7777`
で接続します。

SLIME の replに

```
(sb-int:with-float-traps-masked (:invalid)
 (sdl-examples:particles))
```

を入力し確認します。  
これで問題ないならば、SLIMEの立ち上げ方法に何か問題があるかもしれません。

Comment: 残念ながら、どちらもSlime上ではタイトルバーは白くなってしまいました。escでの終了もできないためsbclの強制終了で終了しました。

Comment: 追記 SLIME環境依存問題の切り分け をしてみました。lispbuilderのバグ報告等も眺めてみましたが、それらしいものは無いみたいですね…。

Comment: slime-connectを実行した後に

Versions differ: 2015-04-19 (slime) vs. 2015-02-19 (swank). Continue? (y or n)

と表示されました。違うバージョンのsbclが入っているようです。

Comment: slime-pathをswankに合わせたところ、slimeのrepl上では正しく動作しましたが、Emacsで一度test.lispに書いた後、C-c C-kでコンパイルしたところ、変わらず、タイトルバーが白塗りでした。

Comment: なるほど、slimeの環境が複数あるのが影響していたのでしょうか。  
quicklispを利用しているということであれば、slimeもquicklispのものを利用するとバージョン違いになることは少ないです。
一度、利用するものを一つだけにして他は削除かロードしない位置に移動してみては如何でしょうか。

Comment: slimeの環境は一致したのですがtest.lispを作ってコンパイルをしたのですがタイトルバーが白塗りになってしまいました。
上記のようにswankを起動してコンパイルをしても同じ結果になってしまいます。
slimeのrepl上で直接入力すればparticlesは正しく動作しました。

Comment: 一点確認させて下さい。コンパイルが必要な場合と、必要でない場合がありますが、何故コンパイルが必要なのでしょうか。test.lispの内容も教えて頂けるとうれしいです。

Comment: test.lispの内容は追記していただいたウィンドウを出す最小限のコードです。
このように短い場合はいいのですが、長いコードを書いた際には、関数を一つ一つReplに打ち込むよりもC−cC−kでコンパイルしてしまう方が早い、というのが理由です。

Comment: なるほど、どちらかというとファイルをロードするためなのですね。  
そうであれば、コードを実行する部分と定義を分けるのが通常です。  
ファイルにはdefunだけにしてC-c C-k(コンパイルしてロード)し、(foo)はreplから実行した場合はどうなりますでしょうか。

Comment: 実行部分と定義を分けたところreplに打ち込み、タイトルバーは表示されるのですが、左上の各種ボタンが灰色のままで、応答しなくなってしまいました。escも反応がありませんでした。

Comment: なるほど。あとは環境依存の問題になってしまうかと思います。  
MacOSXでは動かないのか、user9517さん固有の問題なのかの切り分けになると思うのですが、私はMacOSXの環境を用意できませんので残念ながら私のできるところはここまでかなと思います。  
当面ところは面倒ですが、SLIMEでコードを書き、ターミナルでロードする、という方法で開発されてみては如何でしょうか。
ロードだけターミナルですることになりますが、シンボルの補完等は機能しますのでSLIMEを使う価値は十分あると思います。